# Select 40 most recent sales from each neighborhood group MS Access SQL where ID isn't necessarily distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called Sales that has columns `PARID, PRICE, SALEDT, SALEVAL`, and `NBHD` in it. I need the records that have the 40 most recent `SALEDT` for each `NBHD`. `PARID` uniquely identifies a property, but there could be multiple sales per `PARID`. If my top 40 will give me two rows with the same `PARID`, I only want the one with the most recent `SALEDT`.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a correlated count aggregate subquery to rank order *SalesDT* for each *NBHD*, and then in outer query filter for *rank* less than or equal to 40:

```
SELECT main.NBHD, main.PARID, main.PRICE, main.SALEDT, main.SALEVAL 
FROM 
   (SELECT t.NBHD, t.PARID, t.PRICE, t.SALEDT, t.SALEVAL, 
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable sub
           WHERE sub.NBHD = t.NBHD
           AND sub.SALEDT >= t.SALEDT) AS rank
    FROM mytable t) AS main
WHERE main.rank <= 40
ORDER NBHD, PARID, SALEDT DESC
```